# How to fix Search Console error "Submitted, but not indexed" when "noindex" is intended

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing

The Google Search Console complains, that a few thousand pages are marked as "*Submitted, but not indexed*" but it is correct in a way that we don't want to have these pages in the index, but still browsable by users, hence why we set the meta tag. Am I missing something in my implementation to let Google know that this is correct or should I simply ignore this error?

Edit: The pages are listings that were at some point indexed but when they aren't available anymore we wanna remove them from the index asap

Comment: Why only correct "in a way?"   That sounds completely correct to me.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I meant that it's correct for us but Google still flags it as an error and I'm not sure if i can ignore it because it's correct for us or if there is a way to let Google know that that's what we want to have

Comment: Does Google say that's an error report? I think that's more just informational.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the key is the word "submitted". This suggests that you are actively submitting `noindex` URLs for indexation — probably via an XML sitemap.

In the Coverage report you should see a drop-down menu at the top left, where you can select between all **known** and all **submitted** pages. This might help you to see if you're unintentionally submitting these pages.

[image: Known and submitted page menu in Google Search Console's Coverage report]